# Converting ArcGIS Spatially Enabled Dataframe to GeoJSON

Tags: arcpy, geojson, arcgis-pro, python-3, spatially-enabled-dataframe

I've got a spatially enabled dataframe (SEDF) I'm trying to convert to a GeoJSON.  Normally I do this as a 2 step process by creating a featureclass then converting that into a GeoJSON with `SEDF.spatial.to_featureclass` and `arcpy.conversion.FeaturesToJSON`; however, featureclasses can be cumbersome and it would be nice to skip this step altogether.

ESRI's SEDF website (https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/) states that you can export an SEDF in many formats, including GeoJSON; however, I don't see an example of this process anywhere.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the [API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#geoaccessor) nor `dir(pd.DataFrame.spatial)` has any indication that there is a `to_geojson()` method. So there is no direct way to do this as far as I know.

However, instead of using [`to_featureclass(location)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.GeoAccessor.to_featureclass) where you have to create an actual file, you could use [`to_featureset()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.GeoAccessor.to_featureset).

`to_featureset()` creates an [`arcgis.features.feature.FeatureSet`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#featureset) instance which has a [`to_geojson`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureSet.to_geojson) property. The property's string value can be written to a file using Python's built-in features.

I am not sure if that is the best way to go but it will save you to write an unnecessary file and you can bypass `arcpy`...

---

Using Esri's example from [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#geoaccessor) to get some data to have a working example for demonstration:

```py
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
from arcgis import GIS

gis = GIS()
item = gis.content.get("85d0ca4ea1ca4b9abf0c51b9bd34de2e")
feature_layer = item.layers[0]

# create a Spatially Enabled DataFrame object
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_layer(feature_layer)
```

And here is the code converting the ArcGIS Spatially Enabled Dataframe to a GeoJSON:

```py
featureset = sdf.spatial.to_featureset()

with open(r"d:\temp\test.geojson", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(featureset.to_geojson)
```